# TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly when creating class instances in for loop

Tags: python, class, for-loop

I 'm getting the error "TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly" when using a for loop to create class instances.I'm fairly new to programming and haven't seen this error before

```
class Player(object):  
    properties = []
    def __init__( self, name, wealth, player_number):
        self.name = name
        self.wealth = wealth
        self.player_number = player_number
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.wealth)

players = {}

for x in range(0, Player_count):
    players["player_" + x] = Player(input("Name"), input("Starting Wealth"), x)
```

I'm getting the error when it reaches x

Comment: worth noting here that you don't need a dictionary, since a list will do the job of keeping a track of all the players (especially since you are only tracking them by a number, and lists already have an index) and as side effect it will also get rid of your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn the integer to a string *explicitly* then:

```
 players["player_" + str(x)] = Player(input("Name"), input("Starting Wealth"), x)
```

or use string formatting:

```
 players["player_{}".format(x)] = Player(input("Name"), input("Starting Wealth"), x)
```

You cannot just concatenate a string (`player_`) and an integer (the number between `0` and `Player_count`) referenced by `x`.

Comment: thank you, I was so focused on the last x that i missed the the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add strings and numbers

Incorrect:

```
["player_" + x]
```

Correct:

```
['player_%d' % x']
```

Or the new `format` method:

```
['player_{0}'.format(x)]
```

Comment: Note that this is old-style string formatting, which is recommended against in new code, instead, use `str.format()`. E.g: `'player_{}'.format(x)`.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez: in a later revision, yes. :-)

Comment: Give me a second :D before commenting ;)

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call the `format` method "new", given that it's been in the language since 2.6, 5-odd years ago. But I suppose the New Testament is still new after 2-odd millennia. :)

Comment: @abarnert When you're still maintain software that runs on 2.4 and 2.5 as your day job, it falls into the "new" category ;)

Comment: @ViktorKerkez: I feel for you. At a previous job maybe 5 years ago, I had to figure out where to find Python 1.5 and how to build it on Fedora because my manager insisted that it would be less risk than doing the trivial one-liner change to get our build scripts running in Python 2.5…